# How to get separation between elements that are nested inside an API object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, api

So this is the element that I am fetching my information from

```
   "cards": [
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "5e5d2799faa3d90d054a4c89",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44",
        "556ebb52d0f292916cda2f44"
    ],
```

and this is the code that i am using to retrieve it

```
{item!.cards ? item!.cards : 'none'}
```

The problem Is that all of these elements are rendering in the same line, how do I separate them?

Comment: What rendering system are you using here? React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is React, you would map over each entry in `item.cards` and wrap it in some HTML that does what you want.

Something like:

```
{
  item!.cards ?
    item!.cards.map((card) => <div key={card}>{card}</div>) :
    'none'
}
```